# Get all commit hashes for when a file exactly matches in repo

Tags: git

I have a git repository with about a thousand commits, and I have a JSON file and I know the path of that file in the repository.

This is the bare file I have let's call it `person.json`.

```
{
  "name": "Thomas",
  "age": 30
}
```

I know at some point in the git history this file existed / exists in a git repo. Its relative path was `./people/person.json` and never changes.

Given these three things:

- `REPO_URL`
- local `person.json` file
- the path `./people/person.json`

My goal is to output all the commit hashes where the file `person.json` exactly appears / matches in the repo.

The obvious manual solution is to loop over all commits in a repo, and do a checksum match between the file I have and where the file should be. This possible but would take a long time for many files.

Are there ways of doing this native to git?

Answer (score 2):

That is a plain local operation that would take a pretty small time on your repo on a decent box (not sure about windows)... so, get the hash for the file.... like this:

```
git ls-tree -r HEAD | grep the-file
```

In my case:

```
$ git ls-tree -r HEAD | grep pom.xml
100755 blob some-hash-id    pom.xml
```

You take some-hash-id, and then do this:

```
git log --all --pretty=%h | while read revision; do 
    lines=$( git ls-tree -r $revision | grep some-hash-id | wc -l )
    if [ $lines -gt 0 ]; then
        echo The file is present in $revision
        git ls-tree -r $revision | grep some-hash-id
        echo
    fi
done
```

And that's it.

Comment: To get some-hash-id as seen above from an on disk file that is not the same as HEAD, use `git hash-object -t blob myfile`. **sha1sum will not produce the same answer**, because the blob includes the object type and size as well as content.

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for the native git solution, but I came here looking for any answer and found it's faster to follow the log where a file changed and do an external checksum but this is given smaller files less frequently changed:

```
 cs=$( sha1sum path/file | cut -d' ' -f 1 )
 git log --format="%H" --follow -- path/file | while read a; do
     echo -n "$a "; git --no-pager show $a:path/file | sha1sum
 done | grep -B 1 $cs
```

Among others, `git log sha1..sha1` is a way to view the result(s).